# How can we plot dynamically progressive data in R

Tags: r

I have this data called `mydata`. This data contains `IB_value` columns which is affected by `size`. So for `IB_value1`, it is related to `size1` and `IB_value2` to `size2` and so on. I want to plot IB_values in Y axis and size in X axis and see the progressive change (in 2D lines and not real time plot). Is it possible to plot this in R?

```
  mydata <-structure(c("S05-F13-P01", "S08-F10-P01", "S08-F11-P01", "S09-F66-P01", 
"S09-F67-P01", "S09-F68-P01", "S09-F01-P01", "S09-F02-P01", "S09-F03-P01", 
"S09-F04-P01", "1.05", "1.1", "1.03", "1.11", "1.11", "1.06", 
"1.04", "0.978", "1.05", "1.08", "2251", "1923", "2085", "1954", 
"2105", "2125", "2183", "2179", "1909", "1805", "0.75", "0.8", 
"0.73", "0.81", "0.81", "0.76", "0.74", "0.678", "0.75", "0.78", 
"1230", "902", "1064", "933", "1084", "1104", "1162", "1158", 
"888", "784", "0.55", "0.6", "0.53", "0.61", "0.61", "0.56", 
"0.54", "0.478", "0.55", "0.58", "751", "423", "585", "454", 
"605", "625", "683", "679", "409", "305"), .Dim = c(10L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), c("samples", 
    "IB_value1", "size1", "IB_value2", "size2", "IB_value3", 
    "size3")))
```

Comment: Yes. There is also a `fortune()` to that extend but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way to do it is:

```
#Make data frame
mydf <- as.data.frame(mydata)
#Melt dataframe
mydf_m <- melt(mydf,measure.vars=grep("IB_value", names(mydf), value=TRUE))
#Create index
mydf_m$index <- substr(as.character(mydf_m$variable),nchar(as.character(mydf_m$variable)), nchar(as.character(mydf_m$variable)))
#Replace size based on which variable it is
mydf_m$size_final <- sapply(1:nrow(mydf_m),function(i) as.numeric(as.character(mydf_m[i,paste0("size",mydf_m$index[i])])))

ggplot(data=mydf_m) + geom_line(aes(x=size_final,y=variable))
```

[image]

Basically we melt our dataframe, then we create size based on what value of IB_value we are looking at and the last step is to plot it.

Also if you wanted to add a third dimension such as a time aspect, it would be simple enough to make size correspond to line thickness and then you could track changes in IB_size over time.

## EDIT - Per OPs comment below, plotting for each sample

Edited again as per comments below. See if this is what you want:

```
ggplot(data=mydf_m) + geom_line(aes(x=size_final,y=value, group = samples,color=samples))
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to plot for every sample for all three IB_values and size. Something that would look like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823346/how-to-plot-asymptote-of-a-curve-in-r/36824529?noredirect=1#comment61248926_36824529

Comment: I edited my response. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, but even this does not account for IB_value columns. There should be proportional change in size vs IB values for each sample.

Comment: So the exact plot you want is for each sample, a plot of the numerical IB_values on the y-axis and corresponding size values on the x-axis?

Comment: That is right. I want to see how they progress across the size(X-axes).

Comment: Ok, I edited my response again, let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the output you're looking for? (your data is stored as factors, which may be causing you trouble).

```
require(ggplot2)
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)
d1 <- as.data.frame(apply(mydata[,2:7], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
d2 <- data.frame(IB_value = c(d1$IB_value1, d1$IB_value2, d1$IB_value3), size = c(d1$size1, d1$size2, d1$size3), num = rep(1:3, each = 10))
ggplot(data = d2) + geom_path(aes(x = size, y = IB_value, color = factor(num))
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to plot for every sample for all three IB_values and size. Something that would look like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823346/how-to-plot-asymptote-of-a-curve-in-r/36824529?noredirect=1#comment61248926_36824529